# AS3 - The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller error while removing swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

please help i am getting this error and could not solve with any of the other methods described in all previous posts with similar topic.

Actually here i am loading a swf myMap onto another swf. 
The swf loading works fine, but when try to remove this from stage i get the above said error...

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at actions.classes::MapInteractionManager/unloadSWF()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
```

Here's my as3 code...

```
 var _swfLoader:Loader;
    var _swfContent:MovieClip;

    loadSWF("myMap.swf");  //loading the swf file here

    function loadSWF(path:String):void {
       var _req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
       _req.url = path;

       _swfLoader = new Loader();
       setupListeners(_swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo);

       _swfLoader.load(_req);
    }

    function setupListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
       dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addSWF);
       dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preloadSWF);
    }

    function preloadSWF(event:ProgressEvent):void {
       var _perc:int = (event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal) * 100;
       // swfPreloader.percentTF.text = _perc + "%";
    }

    function addSWF(event:Event):void {
       event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addSWF);
       event.target.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preloadSWF);

       _swfContent = event.target.content;
       _swfContent.addEventListener("close", unloadSWF);

       main.stage.addChild(_swfContent);
    }

    function unloadSWF(event:Event):void {
       _swfLoader.unloadAndStop();

    main.stage.removeChild(_swfContent);  //getting error when trying to remove swf
       _swfContent = null;
    }


    and close event is as,
    _swfContent.dispatchEvent(new Event("close"));
```

Please help, I'm stuck.

here with some update,
i updated code as,

```
function unloadSWF(event:Event):void
{
     if(main.stage.contains(_swfContent))
           main.stage.removeChild(_swfContent);
}
```

Now the error is gone as it is not entering the if loop!!!???

But still i can see that swf on stage:(  plz help

GOT SOLVED...
Thanks everyone for helping...

ToddBFisher did solve it:)

Simply added the _swfLoader to the stage, loaded it, and attached the close listener to it instead of even having a _swfContent. Cut out the middle man and it worked.... Hope this helps...

Comment: Place a `trace(_swfContent, _swfContent.parent)` statement after your call to `unloadAndStop()`, perhaps this method also clears your loaded SWF from your stage's display list, so the statement that throws the error is useless. The manual does not say anything like that, though.

Comment: hey Vesper, thanks for reply... here the problem persists even if i dont use unloadAndStop()

Comment: Okay, if you still see the SWF on the stage, do trace _swfContent.parent somewhere, and its type (`trace(_swfContent.parent is Loader);` will return true if it's Loader, then you can find out if that Loader's parent is your stage).

Comment: thanx again Vesper,                                                             trace(_swfContent.parent); gives [object Stage]
trace(_swfContent.parent is Loader); gives false                                    !!!???

Comment: `trace(main.stage==_swfContent.parent); trace(main.stage==_swfContent.stage);` Sorry, didn't yet work with multiple SWFs, there can be hidden issues about more than a single stage. (Most likely both will return false, but _swfContent.stage will be equal to _swfContent.parent, but this needs to be checked.)

Comment: hey Vesper, both traces resulted 'true'!!!   Anyhow thanks for help, now got it working by removing the middle man _swfContent and directly adding _swfLoader onto stage as guided by ToddBFisher...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall `.unloadAndStop();` does a bunch of cleanup type things, which you are calling right before. It is possible part of the cleanup is removing it from the display list.

Try calling the `removeChild()` before calling `unlodaAndStop()`

```
function unloadSWF(event:Event):void {
    stage.removeChild(_swfContent);  //getting error when trying to remove swf
    _swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
    _swfContent = null;
}
```

**EDIT**

Try simply adding the `_swfLoader` to the stage, load it, and attach the `close` listener to it instead of even having a `_swfContent`. Cut out the middle man and see what happens.

Comment: hey ToddBFisher, thanks for reply.. but doesnt work in my case. i tried dis, if(main.stage.contains(_swfContent)) main.stage.removeChild(_swfContent) the error disappears but i can still see the swf on stage

Answer (score 0):

The error means the child is already removed (or never added)
try to comment out

_swfLoader.unloadAndStop();

to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

`main.stage.removeChild` is already setting  `_swfContent` to null because `removeChild` was fired so  removing the line _`swfContent = null` might solve it.

Comment: hey tariq, thanks for reply...even                              function unloadSWF(event:Event):void {   
    main.stage.removeChild(_swfContent); 
} didnt work!!!

Comment: Try this link,it should help you better understand your problem- http://senocular.com/flash/tutorials/runtimeerrors/#2025